# ARTOOLKIT MULTIPLE MARKER EXAMPLE

Tags: augmented-reality, markers

I have created a working AR model for a single marker.

This consisted of

3d solid (.dae) file.
pattern (.pat) file
marker (.jpg) file)
webcam cameraparameters.dat file

My actionscript CS4 file used 
papervision3d and  flartoolkit

I now wish to move to using multiple markers, but any examples I have seen are not for dae file, they tend to be e.g. cubes, tweening etc. and using flarmanager.

Does anyone have a basic 3d dae file example with 2 models that I could use to move into multiple markers, or provide me with information to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example in my journey to discover all augmented reality features... i'm looking for augmented reality for android, if you know any site, tell me (my email:dpmorocho@gmail.com)

Here is your code:
http://bxmc.poly.edu/blog/arunramkalaiselvan/2010/06/augmented-reality-multiple-collada-models-loading-multiple-markers

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, when I checked out the code I noticed they are using flarmanager and I am using flartoolkit. I don't know if flartoolkit has multiple markers out the box or not, because if not then this could mean I might need to go to flarmanager. thanks for your help, and if I come across anything for android I will let you know